# Allowing users to choose hotkeys

Tags: vb.net

I'd like to have my users be able to choose their own hotkeys for my application, but I'm having some issues with doing this.

I'd like to have a textbot which you can type in and it will put the keys in.
Example: if you type "Ctrl Q O" it will put "CTRL + Q + O" in the textbox, or if you type "Alt S F" it will put "ALT + S + F" and so on.
I have no idea how to do this

Thank you guys so much for your help!

Comment: I have always done that using ComboBox.  That avoids having to figure out Control vs Ctl vs Ctrl vs Cntl.  Same for the keys, that way if Ctrl-Q is defined earlier, you can remove Q from later lists

Comment: How about [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15085/A-simple-hotkey-selection-control-for-NET)?

Comment: You need to get your terminology clear. Ctrl+Q+O is not a hotkey; it's a hotkey followed by a key, or a *key sequence*. Ctrl, Alt and Shift are *modifiers*, and they *modify* the character that follows - note that *character* is singular and not plural. So Ctrl+Q+O is *Ctrl+Q, followed by O*.

Comment: @VisualVincent Yes, like that but in visual basic. Plus, that one is very buggy.

Comment: You do realize that that control is for all .NET languages? That means it works in VB.NET, C#, F#, C++ CLI, etc. You just have to compile it into a .dll file (or convert the source code). **Also**, what do you mean by _"very buggy"_?